# R: Issue with removing rows prior to merging issue

Tags: r, merge

I have two subsets of data which I would like to merge. The date looks like this:

```
Restaurant   Var1
1003         ok
1154         ok
2001         fail
```

and:

```
Restaurant   Var 2
1003         fries
1154         snack
2001         oil
```

Prior to merging I made sure that the restaurant column had the same data by:

```
resvar1 = resvar1[-c(62, 115, 128), ]
resvar2 = resvar2[-47, ]
```

Then I did this:

```
merge(resvar1,resvar2,by=c(Restaurant))
```

But got this instead:

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

I checked whether the column were of the same type and they are both integer. The restaurant column is now equally long because of the removal of some rows. How is it possible I am still getting the error?

Comment: Note that you may use `all.x` or `all.y` to simulate left/right join logic, which would avoid the problem of rows dropping on one side because of no match.

Comment: try saying `by = "Restaurant"` instead. It is looking for a variable names `Restaurant` with the current syntax not a column in the two data frames

Comment: Thanks @Nate and Tim, stupid mistake of me! But I am happy that I can continue now after spending 2 hours on this haha! Have a good day